# Fail to show date array in chart.js labels/x-axis in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I have a django project where a model called EmployeeDayOutput is created with 2 columns output_date (datetime or date field both work) and output_hours (float). In a html page I use chart.js to display the return recordsets from EmployeeDayOutput, where I use the output_date as labels and output_hours as datasets. For example they are respectively ['2023-5-1', '2023-5-2', '2023-5-3'] and [10, 20, 30]. The chart.js formats the html webpage well but it just shows me the wrong dates as [2017, 2016, 2015] instead of the date format.

According to the chart.js examples, the date labels shall take the form as newDateString below.

```js
export function newDateString(days) {
  return DateTime.now().plus({days}).toISO();
}
```

However, the output_date is generated from the server side as defined in the views.py as below:

```python
def empOutputChart(request, employee_id):
    emp_day_outputs = EmpDayOutput.objects.filter(employee_id=employee_id)
    # output_dates = [datetime.datetime.strftime(emp_day_output.output_date, "%Y-%m-%d") for emp_day_output in emp_day_outputs]
    # new_dates = [date.replace("'", "\\'") for date in output_dates]
    output_dates = [emp_day_output.output_date for emp_day_output in emp_day_outputs]
    output_hours = [emp_day_output.output_hours for emp_day_output in emp_day_outputs]

    # Pass the data to the template.
    context = {
        'emp_day_outputs': emp_day_outputs,
        'output_dates': output_dates,
        'output_hours': output_hours,
    }
    return render(request, 'vismanager/employee_day_output_chart.html', context)
```

As you can see, I try to format the output_dates as string instead of date array or datetime array (I had tried both as defined in the models.py) but it simply don't work out. Any idea?

I have tried changing the output_dates into string array from server side (inside the views.py file) and I've also tied to force the output_dates into new Date(empDayOutput.output_date) format, which could be shown properly in chart.js as the examples show.

But none of these work out.

Comment: Indeed, even javascript's Date parses correctly dates in the format like `2023-5-1`; still, with minimal preprocessing it can be transformed to [ISO8601](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) which will be parsed by all adapters. Please post your (resulting) javascript code, ideally a working example; most importantly your chart.js settings object; you haven't yet said what [adapter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters) you're using, let alone the options.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve the problem with following codes:

```
{% for emp_day_output in emp_day_outputs %}
                new Date("{{ emp_day_output.output_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}").toLocaleDateString(),
            {% endfor %}
```

With the new Date().toLocaleDateString() function, it makes the html with javascript convert the date string for displaying the chart axis provided by the chart.js.